# Movie I saw in 1990s With Tentacles & an Explosive Finale

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw this when I was young, and I only caught the climactic ending.

- A man is running through some sort of industrial facility. Up on a cat walk, the background has a red lit hue to it. There is some sort of meltdown or explosion pending at this facility. This man is on a tight timeline to get out.
- Tentacles are attacking him as he goes. There is a menacing close-up of the tentacles, showing toothed rings. The tentacles are a darkish red.
- The man escapes the facility, and the whole thing explodes. The view of the explosion reveals that the facility was beach-side.
- This explosion was clearly part of their plan to eliminate the beast.

This is what I remember. I have a vague recollection of my father commenting on the movie, and something about a government experiment gone wrong.

I saw this live-action movie on television in the US in the mid to late 1990s. It could easily have been older, but was in color and had decent effects.

Comment: What about DEEP RISING (1998) [(youtube link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g959vHlzP6w)? It is not a facility in the end, but a big luxury cruise ship.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, lets have some images that match [DEEP RISING](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118956/),
plus see that [ending scene on youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g959vHlzP6w)

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118956/)

> A group of heavily armed hijackers board a luxury ocean liner in the
> South Pacific Ocean to loot it, only to do battle with a series of
> large-sized, tentacled, man-eating sea creatures who had already
> invaded the ship.

Escape, tentacles:
[image]

More of "facility":
[image]

Some teeth in tentacles:
[image]

Creature consumed by fire:
[image]

Liner explosion:
[image]

Finally our heroes reach the beach, only to find something else:
[image]

Comment: Finally got a chance to watch it, this is indeed the answer.